# Expanding a factorial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

Can you explain me how we got this identity?

$$\frac{1}{(3n)!}$$
the same as
$$\frac{(3n)!}{(3n+3)!}$$
I have been trying to expand, but didn't get the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Because they are not same.

Comment: Well, I guess I have noted it falsely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expand $$(3n+3)!=(3n+3)\times(3n+2)\times(3n+1)\times(3n)!$$ So $$\frac{(3n)!}{(3n+3)!}=\frac 1 {(3n+3)\times(3n+2)\times(3n+1)}$$

Comment: @Questionnaire. You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

they are not same , consider $n=1$ , you have $\frac{1}{3!}=\frac{1}{6}$ and on the other hand $\frac{3!}{6!}= \frac{1}{120}$

Comment: Could we expand it with ((3n)!/(3n)!)? How would it look like?